# From Spring data JPA Spring Cloud AWS

Tags: spring-data-jpa, porting, spring-cloud

I'm at design phase of my project and I have a doubt. 
I'm modelling my system and I will use Spring Data JPA for persistence layer. Although, there is high chances of cloud deploy. Is it traumatic the portability from Spring Data JPA to Spring Clous AWS (RDS)? I didn't find direct metion about this kind of integration.
I'm trying to avoid a waste code in future.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are actually two separate things. Spring Cloud AWS JDBC will just configure a DataSource while Spring Data JPA is going to use it.

So you can use Spring Data JPA and you will be able to move your application to AWS without much efforts (basically just changing the way the DataSource is setup).